# How to queue a non-existing worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm trying to queue a Sidekiq worker that does not exist in my project but exists in some other project sharing the same redis server.

In our current situation, we have two servers:

- **API server** runs on Heroku. Web instance for the REST API and worker with Sidekiq listening to the `:api` queue.
- **Processing server** runs on AWS ElasticBeanstalk with a puma instance running a REST Full API with Sinatra. This instance runs Sidekiq and listens to the queue `:processing`

*Side note*: In the beginning, our API was doing all the work but as some workers started taking too much memory, we switch to the processing server.

---

When we need to execute a job on the processing server we have these actions happening:

1. API calls `POST processing.com/some_job`
2. Processing queues `SomeJobWorker` on queue `processing`
3. Processing executes `SomeJobWorker` from queue `processing`
4. Processing calls `POST api.com/webhooks/some_job_result`
5. API queues `SomeJobResultWorker` on queue `api`
6. API executes `SomeJobResultWorker` from queue `processing`

---

This got me thinking if I could somehow, from the **API server** directly queue `SomeJobWorker` then I could get rid of the REST API on our **processing server**.

... then I could get rid of the `webhooks` endpoint on the **API server** and do the same from the **processing server**

I would end up with something like this:

1. API calls queues `SomeJobWorker`
2. Processing executes `SomeJobWorker`
3. Processing queues `SomeJobResultWorker`
4. API executes `SomeJobResultWorker`

Is there a way for me to queue a worker that does not exist on my local code base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two shards. Each Redis is a shard. Read this page:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Sharding

You can push a job using the class name:

```
client = Sidekiq::Client.new(PROCESSING_REDIS)
client.push('queue' => 'api', 'class' => 'FooWorker', 'args' => [1,2,"foo"])
```

Comment: I marked as it sovles my problem because your `Client.new` seems to be exactly what I wanted and I don't know how I did not figure that out on my own...

Comment: Regarding the sharding, it seems to allow the same code base to use 2 redis different redis servers and to balance what goes where. While in my example I want 2 different base codes to share the same redis server

Comment: As long as they don't share any queues, this might work but it's not officially supported.  Different codebases should have different Redis configs so their data is  physically distinct, just like their code.